# Vafa-Witten theorem for gravitational $\theta$-term

Tags: quantum-field-theory, gravity, symmetry, gauge-theory

"The Vafa–Witten theorem shows that vector-like global symmetries such as isospin and baryon number in vector-like gauge theories like QCD cannot be spontanteously broken as long as the theta angle is zero.", as stated in the corresponding [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vafa%E2%80%93Witten_theorem).

Does this theorem also hold true for the gravitational theta angle, if we treat gravity as a gauge theory?

Comment: Intresting quaetion. But there is statement, that in grvity there are no global symmetries..